# Integrating Dialogflow with an already existing project on actions on Google

Tags: deployment, dialogflow-es, integration, actions-on-google

First of all, thanks for taking the time to read through our issue.

So, we have a Dialogflow project connected to an already existing google project. When we try to test our skills on google by the Integrations tab, it displays an error 'Precondition check failed' without any more information, even though it still updates and uses our Dialogflow intents as it should.

[image]

The problem comes when we update anything on the actions console or try to make an alpha deploy of our skill. The moment we change anything, it comes back to the default configuration with the message 'Start building your action by defining the main invocation.' on the main invocation.

We have no clue how to handle this problem or if we have to configure something special on either of the systems to make it work. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Hello, do you have enough permissions to create integrations with dialogflow, [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/access-control#roles)? Can you give me more details about what happened, were you able to create an intents and test them?  In addition, about the integration with Google assistant, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/aog), there is a new development platform with a built-in conversation builder which does not need to integrate with Dialogflow.

Comment: Hi, I have just checked and it seems like I have enough permissions to create the integration. As I said I am able to test Dialogflow intents when I update them via the Dialogflow integrations tab, however, they don't seem to work when I update anything using the actions on google console.

Comment: Now that you talk about the new google development platform, I feel like that may be causing us those problems. Maybe they are entering into some kind of conflict, I'll investigate this new path you have just open. 
Thanks a lot for your answer! I'll keep you updated with any progress I make in the following days.

Comment: Since this might be the solution for you. Would you mind if I post the answer ? So it can further contribute to the community and also be of any further help. Also I would appreciate if you would upvote and accept it.

Comment: Sure! you can post an answer if you feel like it will help anyone, no problem there :) 

I didn't find a solution yet, couldn't find anything following that path. Although I manage to see that our cloud project didn't have the dialog cloud service account configured, so I had to create it manually. I'm currently stuck there. No clue what should be our next step.

Comment: I see you are starting with Dialogflow now. I encourage you to see these documentations links, [1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup) and [2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick). Both explain essential points before diving into  Dialogflow. What is that you want to achieve with Dialogflow so I can help you more specifically? Or are you just testing it ?

Comment: Regarding the Google assistant new platform, these are two links for the documentation which explains more about it, [link1](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview) and [link2](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart). Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to integrate the Google Assistant with Dialoflow, I strongly recommend you check the new development Google Assistant's platform with a built-in conversation builder, [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/aog). Furthermore, there is a [quick start](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart) guide and [conversational actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview) guide.

As I mentioned in the first comment, you need to have appropriate permissions to create an interaction within Dialogflow, you can check the pre-defined roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/access-control). In addition, since you are starting with Dialogflow, I would advise you to start with the available [quick-starts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick) and the [setup tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup), which explains how to begin using Dialogflow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Alexandre, in the end, we had to create a new Dialogflow project connected to a totally blank cloud project so it configures itself properly, no idea what was happening with the other one. Now everything works like a charm.